# Hide CIFS mounts in Launcher and Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am adding some Samba network shares in `/etc/fstab` for **Documents** and **Pictures** folder etc. in Ubuntu 16.04.

This works but Ubuntu shows these shares in the Launcher which I don't want. I can choose **Unlock from Laucher** to hide these but is there a way to configure this automatically for the user?

I tried to use `UDISKS_IGNORE` in a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-udisks2.rules` but I am not sure what to add there. I don't think this works for Samba shares.

Also, in Nautilus, I don't want to see these shares. The user doesn't have permissions to mount/umount these drives.

How can I tell Nautilus to show these shares as ordinary folders?

See pictures [image: Network shares in Nautilus], [image: Network shares in Nautilus] and [image: Network shares in Launcher]

Answer (score 2):

try to add the mount option `x-gvfs-hide` to your `/etc/fstab` lines.